# Kotlin Multiplatform Configuration issue

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I continue getting Gradle configuration error in my KMP + Jetpack Compose project

A problem occurred configuring project ':shared'.

> Configuration with name 'testApi' not found.

My setup is:

1. Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Canary 3
2. Project level setup

```
dependencies {
   classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha03")
   classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.20")
}
```

3. 'shared module'

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
}

kotlin {
    android()
    ios {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "shared"
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1")
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation("junit:junit:4.13.1")
            }
        }
        val iosMain by getting
        val iosTest by getting
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(30)
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(21)
        targetSdkVersion(30)
    }
}

val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    group = "build"
    val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
    val sdkName = System.getenv("SDK_NAME") ?: "iphonesimulator"
    val targetName = "ios" + if (sdkName.startsWith("iphoneos")) "Arm64" else "X64"
    val framework = kotlin.targets.getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>(targetName).binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)
    val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    into(targetDir)
}

tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)
```

Note:
By removing the configuration part by part, I seem to figure out w
that the problem seems to be around the android configuration itself,
so if I remove android() part from

```
kotlin {
    android()
    ....
```

and just go with simple jvm() it goes well

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175496966

Comment: oh, that's unfortunate, what would be the best way to deal with it?
should i rollback to previous android studio version and use previous gradle plugins?
also form the issue in there i can see that some fixes to AGP coming in Canary 5 of android studio
is there some to track when it's coming?

Comment: I hadn't updated here yet but I've heard of other people rolling back to get around this for now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Fixed issue in `Kotlin 1.5 M1` (pending)

The problem is in Canary or AGP 7.0.0:

- IDE: Canary 11
- distributionUrl: 6.8.2
- 7.0.0-alpha11

---

### Workaround 1:

IMPORTANT: Make sure the file is groovy or dsl

**PRECONDITION**: These configurations have to be done in all modules / sub-modules of the project that are KMM and the `android {}` block has to be before the `kotlin {}` block

For Kotlin DSL:

#### build.gradle.kts (:kmm_shared)

```
android {
    configurations {
        create("androidTestApi")
        create("androidTestDebugApi")
        create("androidTestReleaseApi")
        create("testApi")
        create("testDebugApi")
        create("testReleaseApi")
    }
}
kotlin { }
```

For Groovy:

#### build.gradle (:kmm_shared)

```
android {
    configurations {
        androidTestApi {}
        androidTestDebugApi {}
        androidTestReleaseApi {}
        testApi {}
        testDebugApi {}
        testReleaseApi {}
    }
}
kotlin { }
```

Also, you should to use AGP 7.0 because previous versions of gradle generate problems.

#### build.gradle.kts (:project) && build.gradle.kts (:buildSrc)

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha11")
}
```

---

### Workaround 2 (Deprecated)

Temporarily use a maximum of the beta versions:

- IDE: Beta 6
- `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip`
- `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0-beta06'`

---

Good Luck

- [issue/KT-43944](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43944)
- [commit in Mobius](https://github.com/Coronel-B/Mobius-KMM/commit/f83b0ba237074efd7b80f900fefeb230c77816e0)

Answer (score 38):

You can use the below code as a workaround in your shared module Gradle file

```
android {
    configurations {
        create("androidTestApi")
        create("androidTestDebugApi")
        create("androidTestReleaseApi")
        create("testApi")
        create("testDebugApi")
        create("testReleaseApi")
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: This has to be put before the kotlin {} block

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. Can you share a resource to understand why this works?

Comment: It's caused by a bug in kotlin KMM config - the bugs fixed and should be in 1.5.0. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43944

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me. So, why this work?